# Serializing string with escaped double quotes to XML

Tags: java, jackson

I have a problem trying to serialize a Java Object to XML using jackson XmlMapper.

One of the fields contains a string with escaped double quotes, like this:

`String example = "This is a string with \"escaped double quotes\"";`

When i pass object to XMLmapper
(variables is the object containing example string):

```
  XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
  String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(variables);
```

this is the output i get:

```
some other tags
<example>This is a string with "escaped double quotes""This is a string with "escaped double quotes""This is a string with "escaped double quotes"</example>
some other tags
```

How can i serialize a string with escaped doubled quotes to XML achieving proper result, i.e.

```
<example>This is a string with "escaped double quotes"</example>
```

Comment: hi & welcome! ;) Where do you "get the output"? (Sorry, cannot reproduce: I get the output (from `System.out.println(xml);`): `<SimpleBean><example>This is a string with "escaped double quotes"</example></SimpleBean>`)

Comment: @xerx593 i printed it out in the console, same as you.

Comment: Are you sure you haven’t attempted to escape the string yourself somehow?  (It’s not necessary to do that.)

Comment: @VGR No, the string is parsed from received JSON and prior to calling xmlMapper it looks exactly as in "example" variable in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Then: "Sorry, cannot reproduce"!

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-mapper</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version> <!-- tried [2.11.0 - 2.13.0], same result -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

src/main/java/com/example/xml/mapper/SimpleBean.java:

```java
package com.example.xml.mapper;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SimpleBean {
    final String example = "This is a string with \"escaped double quotes\"";
}
```

src/main/java/com/example/xml/mapper/Main.java:

```java
package com.example.xml.mapper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException  {
        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(new SimpleBean());
        System.out.println(xml);
    }
}
```

... `>mvn clean package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.xml.mapper.Main` (jdk8), prints:

```
...

--- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ xml-mapper ---
<SimpleBean><example>This is a string with "escaped double quotes"</example></SimpleBean>
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.570 s
Finished at: 2021-11-16T13:02:33+01:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: ..also no changes (works like charm ;-( ), on "mutable" bean...